# By default today's date active in daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

How to remove today's date active in predefined range of date range picker. I have used http://www.daterangepicker.com/ daterangepicker as mentioned in this link

## Script

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({

        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }        
    }, function (start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));       
    });

view
======
<div id="datepicker">

<span id="datepicker-heading">Created On</span><br />

<div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
  <span>Select Date</span> <b class="caret"></b>
  </div>
  </div>
```

while page loading date range picker shows **Select Date** by default. But today is highlighted below

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the daterangepicker?

Comment: I have posted pls check

Comment: Why don't you use the startDate and endDate properties? I believe you can also use setStartDate() and setEndDate() methods as well.

Comment: By default I need to pass null value

Answer (score 0):

The "today" highlighting is built in to the daterangepicker, and does not have a native method/parameter that you can use to disable it. The easiest thing to do is just to over-ride the default CSS styling for the active date:

```
.daterangepicker td.active, .daterangepicker td.active:hover {
     background-color: #fff; 
     border-color: #fff; 
     color: #000; 
}
```

NOTE: This will prevent any highlighting from occurring when the user selects a date.

Comment: we can remove the "today" highlighting option using this, but today is **active** always, not able to click